# Как вычислить сумму ключей объекта в массиве-javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript

Как посчитать общую сумму orders.price отдельно для каждого объекта?

```
const orders = [
{
    id: 1,
    tableNum: 24,
    waiter: 'Alisa',
    orderedDate: '5:14',
    orders: [
        {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 10000},
        {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 15000},
        {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 8000},
        {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 7000},

    ]
},
{
    id: 2,
    tableNum: 23,
    waiter: 'Ivan',
    orderedDate: '6:14',
    orders: [
        {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 10000},
        {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 15000},
        {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 8000},
        {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 7000},

    ]
}
]
```

---

```
let total_sum = 0 
orders.forEach((function(order){ 
  order.orders.forEach((function(item){ 
    total_sum += item.price
    return total_sum 
  })) 
  console.log(total_sum) 
  total_sum = 0 
}))
```

Comment: А что вы пробовали?)

Comment: let total_sum = 0
        orders.forEach((function(order){
            order.orders.forEach((function(item){
                total_sum += item.price
                return total_sum
            }))
            console.log(total_sum)
            total_sum = 0
        }))

Comment: Но я хочу сохранить каждую сумму и передать туда куда надо а этого у меня пока не получается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

`orders.forEach(obj => obj.total = obj.orders.reduce((sum, order) => sum + order.price, 0));`

Для каждого объекта `obj` в массиве, создает дополнительное поле `total`, куда записывает сумму всех `.price` из его `.orders`

```js
const orders = [
  {
    id: 1,
    tableNum: 24,
    waiter: 'Alisa',
    orderedDate: '5:14',
    orders: [
      {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 10000},
      {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 15000},
      {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 8000},
      {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 7000},
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tableNum: 23,
    waiter: 'Ivan',
    orderedDate: '6:14',
    orders: [
      {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 10000},
      {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 15000},
      {title: 'Something', count: 1, price: 8000},
      {title: 'Something', count: 2, price: 7000},
    ]
  }
];

orders.forEach(obj => obj.total = obj.orders.reduce((sum, order) => sum + order.price, 0));

console.log(orders);
```

Comment: Все супер!) Спасибо вам большое

Answer (score 2):

А что там сложного?

```
let map = new Map(orders.map(({id,orders})=>
  [id,orders.reduce((sum,{count,price})=>
    sum+count*price,0
  )]
));
console.log(map);
```

Comment: неправильно считает)

Comment: А по-моему правильно.

Comment: @SaidbekAhmadbekov домножение каждого price на count, наверно лишнее? А так, правильно.

Comment: да без умножения все ок:) спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Можно даже так, чтобы не пересчитывать каждый раз при изменении состава заказа:

```js
const orders = [{
    id: 1,
    tableNum: 24,
    waiter: 'Alisa',
    orderedDate: '5:14',
    orders: [{
        title: 'Something',
        count: 2,
        price: 10000
      },
      {
        title: 'Something',
        count: 1,
        price: 15000
      },
      {
        title: 'Something',
        count: 1,
        price: 8000
      },
      {
        title: 'Something',
        count: 2,
        price: 7000
      },

    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    tableNum: 23,
    waiter: 'Ivan',
    orderedDate: '6:14',
    orders: [{
        title: 'Something',
        count: 2,
        price: 10000
      },
      {
        title: 'Something',
        count: 1,
        price: 15000
      },
      {
        title: 'Something',
        count: 1,
        price: 8000
      },
      {
        title: 'Something',
        count: 2,
        price: 7000
      },

    ]
  }
]
orders.forEach(order => {
  Object.defineProperty(order, 'total', {
    get: function() {
      return this.orders.reduce((sum, order) => sum + order.price * order.count, 0);
    }
  })
});

console.log(orders[0].total)
orders[0].orders.push({
  title: 'Something else',
  count: 10,
  price: 2000
})
console.log(orders[0].total)
```

Comment: Да реально круто!!!))) Спасибо!